# App is getting restarted when trying to take picture from camera in android build 8,9 and in ios build is crashing - IONIC 4

Tags: ionic-framework, webview, background

This is error I am getting in ios
2020-04-07 12:11:24.299057+0530 Engage Local[43212:627996] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]
: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _alwaysRunsAtForegroundPriority.'

It all started when I used cordova-plugin-ionic-webview:^4.1.3 and cordova-plugin-background-mode:^0.7.3

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in ios plist file details about camera and photo storage.

Camera:

Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use

Photo:

Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use

Comment: <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>
                 This app needs access to your Camera to allow you to take and upload a picture.
        </string>
   </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*- 
 Info.plist">
            <string>
                  This app needs access to your Photo Library for uploading files
         </string>
        </config-file>